# HighCharts doesnt get data from Flask endpoint

Tags: flask, charts, highcharts

I use the code of "***Live data from dynamic CSV***" from Highcharts Demos as a basis for my need. As it gets data lively from a web service url, I just change it to get data from my Flask endpoint. That is to say, I use the same code to be served with Flask.
Even if the flask endpoint serves the same content, I don't get it to work. I just changed the url of "https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-data.csv" with `/data`. And here `/data` serves the totally same kind of ***csv*** output.
So far I could not obtain the result.

Demo code located in "https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/live-data/" is used.

```
var defaultData = '/data';
```

Comment: Your file in flask should be a streaming file data in order to work with that example code.

Comment: just the same way original demo code does, my "/data"endpoint also gives new values as json output everytime it is polled. I verified that by querying "http://0.0.0.0:5000/data" on address bar of web browser.

Comment: Is there any JS error about Highcharts? This looks like a problem with flask and data and not a problem with Highcharts or charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have to use "http://10.0.2.2:5000/data" instead of "0.0.0.0:5000/data". Because 10.0.2.2 is the special alias to host loopback interface (aka 127.0.0.1).